# Tensor Product of a Vector Space & the corresponding Field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $K$ be a field and $V$ a vector space of finite dimension $n$ over $K$  also suppose $K\subset{F}$ and let ${V_F}={F}\otimes_K V$ the tensor product over $K$ of $V$ and ${F}$.

I have proved that $V_F$ forms a vector space over $F$ naturally but I need to prove that $\dim _F  V_F \leq \dim_K V_F$. I  also have to find the example when the strict inequality holds.

Kindly help!!

Any hints will be appreciated.

thanks & regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dim V_F(F) \times \dim (F(K)) = \dim V_F(K)$$

See I have thought of like extension of fields. Is it helpful?